# Are there any VSCode extensions that will connect to BigQuery?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code, google-bigquery

I'm using VSCode to query into a Snowflake DWH using an extension (SQLTools and the SNowflake driver).

Is there a similar VSCode extension I can use to run SQL queries in BigQuery?

Comment: You maybe also interested in GCP Project Switcher extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pentium10.vscode-gcp-project-switcher

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I made a simple search in GG and here is the first result:
https://github.com/google/vscode-bigquery

I think you should do some search before asking.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't been worked on in 3 years and doesn't look like it's been released properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try [BigQuery Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=minodisk.bigquery-runner).
It is an extension that queries BigQuery and displays the results.

I'm not sure if it fits your requirements perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [BigQuery SQLTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Evidence.sqltools-bigquery-driver) extension helpful.

It's a free, open-source ([GitHub](https://github.com/evidence-dev/sqltools-bigquery-driver)) extension that allows you to query and explore BigQuery from VSCode.

Features:

- Connect via the CLI, Service Account or OAuth
- Run queries and get results into VSCode
- Explore datasets, tables and columns in the sidebar
- View table contents by selecting them in the sidebar
- Auto-complete for common keywords (e.g. SELECT, FROM, WHERE)

Disclosure: I built this